# Using relationships between Rails models in folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Error**

```
uninitialized constant Suspicious::Activity::SuspiciousPerson
```

**Model structure**

```
app
  models
    suspicious
      activity.rb
      person.rb
```

**Model classes**

```
class Suspicious::Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :suspicious_people, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :suspicious_people, :allow_destroy => true

class Suspicious::Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :suspicious_activity
```

**This is where the error occurs [line 3]**

```
1 def new
2   @activity = Suspicious::Activity.new
3   @activity.suspicious_people.build
4 end
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're namespacing models like this, you don't need to prepend 'suspicious_' when referencing to models with the same name.

Model

```
class Suspicious::Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :people, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Suspicious::Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :activity
end
```

Controller

```
def new
  @activity = Suspicious::Activity.new
  @activity.people.build
end
```